# Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘(Controller -> IO ()) -> IO ()’

Tags: haskell, io, controller, genetic-algorithm, ioerror

I'm a newbie in Haskell, I took this error when I try to configure my code. I understand that all of instructions in main() need to be an IO(), and the error happened because one of function I used (in Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Animate) didn't return IO(). I wanna display the result of a genetic algorithm by using gloss package.
Here is my code:

```
module Main where

import Prelude as P
import Control.Monad.Random as Rand
import Data.Functor
import Data.IORef
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Animate
import Graphics.Solution
import Graphics.Plot

import Args
import Task
import Parsing
import Genetic

import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan
import Control.Monad.STM
import Control.Arrow (first)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- parseOptions 

  opts <- loadEvolOptions (evolOptionsFileName args)
  gen <- newStdGen
  task@(Task _ twrs _ _) <- loadTask (inputFileName args) (fitnessFuncFileName args)

  chan <- newTChanIO
  asolution <- async $ solve chan gen opts task
  dataRef <- newIORef []
  finalSolutionRef <- newIORef Nothing

  animateIO mode white $ const $ do
      mfinsol <- readIORef finalSolutionRef
      case mfinsol of
        Just solution -> do
          samples <- readIORef dataRef
          return $ solutionPicture task solution (fitnessPlot samples)
        Nothing -> do
          msolution <- poll asolution     
          case msolution of
            Nothing -> do
              mv <- atomically $ tryReadTChan chan
              case mv of
                Nothing -> return ()
                Just v -> modifyIORef dataRef (++[v])
              samples <- readIORef dataRef
              return $ fitnessPlot samples
            Just esol -> case esol of
              Left e -> fail $ show e
              Right solution -> do
                saveResult (outputFileName args) (filterTowers solution twrs)
                writeIORef finalSolutionRef (Just solution)
                samples <- readIORef dataRef
                return $ solutionPicture task solution (fitnessPlot samples)
      where mode = InWindow "test_genetic_al" (1280, 1024) (10, 10)
            fitnessPlot ds =  translate (-300) (-200) $ scale 600 600 $ plot "generation" "fitness" $ first fromIntegral <$> ds
```

And this is which I got:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’
                with actual type ‘(Controller -> IO ()) -> IO ()’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      animateIO mode white
      $ const
        $ do { mfinsol <- readIORef finalSolutionRef;
               case mfinsol of {
                 Just solution -> do { ... }
                 Nothing -> do { ... } } }
    In the expression:
      do { args <- parseOptions;
           opts <- loadEvolOptions (evolOptionsFileName args);
           gen <- newStdGen;
           task@(Task _ twrs _ _) <- loadTask
                                       (inputFileName args) (fitnessFuncFileName args);
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { args <- parseOptions;
                 opts <- loadEvolOptions (evolOptionsFileName args);
                 gen <- newStdGen;
                 .... }
          where
              mode = InWindow "test_genetic_al" (1280, 1024) (10, 10)
              fitnessPlot ds
                = translate (- 300) (- 200)
                  $ scale 600 600
                    $ plot "generation" "fitness" $ first fromIntegral <$> ds
```

I've been searching my problem over Google and stackoverflow for so many times but still cannot find a solution for this error. Please help me.

P/S: This is a guide line for Graphics.Gloss: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.11.1.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-IO-Animate.html

Sorry again for my silly question, after I gave Lazersmoke's suggestion (which you can see below in the comment area), I got another error which very similar with the error I asking for:

I changed the line: animateIO mode white $ const $ do

Into: animateIO mode white (_ -> return ()) $ const $ do

```
Couldn't match type ‘Picture’ with ‘()’
    Expected type: Controller -> IO ()
      Actual type: Controller -> IO Picture
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘const
       $ do { mfinsol <- readIORef finalSolutionRef;
              case mfinsol of {
                Just solution -> do { ... }
                Nothing -> do { ... } } }’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      animateIO mode white (\ _ -> return ())
      $ const
        $ do { mfinsol <- readIORef finalSolutionRef;
               case mfinsol of {
                 Just solution -> do { ... }
                 Nothing -> do { ... } } }
    In the expression:
      do { args <- parseOptions;
           opts <- loadEvolOptions (evolOptionsFileName args);
           gen <- newStdGen;
           task@(Task _ twrs _ _) <- loadTask
                                       (inputFileName args) (fitnessFuncFileName args);
           .... }
```

Comment: The error just means that you forgot to supply one parameter, in this case that `Controller -> IO ()` function.

Comment: So how can I fix it, could you please show me the way?

Comment: What he said, namely "Callback to take the display controller." as you can see in the documentation you linked. You need something like `animateIO mode white (\_ -> return ()) $ const $ do` to satisfy the type, although you probably need to provide an actual callback there based on your intentions to make it work properly.

Comment: More generally, I would try to extract some functions to make this block smaller and/or add type annotation to have a better, more targeted error message.

Comment: @ThaoDang, try splitting up the function in more manageable pieces like Jean-Baptiste suggested, and look at the type of each. In particular, this latest error means that the callback is not supposed to return a `Picture`, but the `do` block should just end by returning unit (`()`).

Comment: This is completely unrelated to your problem, but your understanding ("all of instructions in main() need to be an IO()") is incorrect. Having statements of type `IO a` for any `a` is fine and common.

Answer (score 1):

How many arguments does `animateIO` take?

```
animateIO :: Display    
          -> Color  
          -> (Float -> IO Picture)  
          -> (Controller -> IO ())  
          -> IO ()
```

Four. How many arguments did you provide to `animateIO`?

```
animateIO mode white $ …
```

Three. The type of

```
animateIO mode white $ …
```

is `(Controller -> IO ()) -> IO ()`, which is exactly what your error message tells you. Since you don't want to use the `Controller -> IO ()` part, you can provide your own `animateIO`:

```
animateIO' :: Display -> Color -> IO Picture -> IO ()
animateIO' m c a = animateIO m c (const a) (const $ return ())
```

Note that your `(\_ -> return ())` did not work because the third argument has to produce a `Picture`, not a `IO ()`.

Comment: I will fix my code like what you advice and post the result as soon as possible, thank you for helping me.